# mount: only root can use "--types" option (effective UID is 2000)

Tags: debian, containers, mount

I tried to execute the mount command inside my debian:9 container but getting issue as follows even though running as a root use.

container run command:

```
docker run --privileged --userns=host  -it --rm -u root <customimage with debian:9> /bin/sh
```

mount command inside the container

```
mkdir -p /tmp/overlay
mount -t tmpfs tmpfs /tmp/overlay
```

exception

```
mount: only root can use "--types" option (effective UID is 2000)
```